# Should I recreate the Authorization token for DocumentDB Rest APIs every time

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When using the Azures DocumentDB via REST I need to create a request with some specific headers [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/common-documentdb-rest-request-headers).

One needs to run some confusing code to [create the authorization token](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN). After having done this one can access the addressed resource for 15 min (per default) before the authorization token expires and needs to be recreated.

All of this is understood.

My question is: why not simply create the authorization token new for every single request? This would free my code from having some partial state on the client. The downside is of course that it takes slightly more time to recreate that authorization token every time - however that should be neglectable as much more time is spend on the network level.

Any advises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: why not simply create the authorization token new for every single request?

As far as I know, in most scenarios we generate the **authorization token** for per request to access to (or operate) DocumentDB resources.

Besides, if we use an existing and  no expired authorization token, we need to pass the **same date** (that is used in StringToSign to generate signature) as `x-ms-date` header in the request, otherwise, it would also return 401 (or 403) error.

*List databases*

[image]

*Different date (Wed, 26 Apr 2017 06:40:44 GMT)is passed as x-ms-date, it will return 401 (or 403) error*

[image]